# If I set up Apple Mail, will it delete my emails?

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email

I was trying to set up Apple Mail on my Mac because someone emailed me a `.eml` file that I seem to need Apple Mail in order to open. When I tried setting up my Gmail account in Apple Mail, it asked me to give permission for the app to read, edit, and delete emails.

**What I Want To Know:** Under what circumstances would Apple Mail actually delete my emails from a Gmail account that I set up with it? Would it only be when I manually delete them in the Apple Mail app?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set up an account to read a single email file.

Comment: Answering your secondary question: Giving permission to Apple Mail for your Google account should be fairly safe. Apple Mail only deletes mail you tell it to. I've set my G Suite and Google Accounts to read in Apple Mail many times through the years without incident. Unless you think you'll use Apple Mail, I would probably skip the setup as Allan mentions.

Answer (score 5):

The .eml file is a mail file that is based on the [MIME RFC 822](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa493918(v=exchg.140)) specification.  It's basically a text format that pretty much all Mail applications can open

- Outlook (macOS, Windows, iOS, Android) / Outlook Express (Windows Only)
- Microsoft Mail (Windows 10)
- Apple Mail (macOS)
- [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/)

Regarding your question, you don't need to setup a Gmail acccount (or any account for that matter) to read a single .eml file.  If it asks you to set one up, just skip it.

You can also open a .eml in your browser.  Simply rename the file with an .mht extension.  Assuming the file is on your Desktop, using Terminal

```
% mv ~/Desktop/foobar.eml ~/Desktop/foobar.mht
```

Then open with your browser.  If it's only text, any browser will work, but if it has embedded images, Chrome or [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) will natively display it (I prefer Edge over Chrome as it uses the same engine, but I distrust Microsoft less than I do Google).

Microsoft Word will natively open both a .eml and the .mht.  If you don't have Word, you can open it with the [free web version of Word](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/free-office-online-for-the-web).  You just need to create a free Microsoft account.

As an example, I got an old .eml file (an Uber receipt) and tested.  It opens natively in

- Outlook for macOS
- Apple Mail
- Microsoft Word
- Edge/Chrome (as a text file)

[image] [image]

[image]